# postgis st_relate polygon inside another and sharing a boundary

Tags: postgis, boundaries, de-9im

I am trying to select polygons inside an other one WITH a common boundary.
It seems that st_relate is the way but I can't find the right matrix, even if I don't see where the fault is in :

```
st_relate(e.geom, d.geom, '2FF11F212')
```

[image: For example I want to select the bottom green polygon only]

[For example I want to select the bottom green polygon only

Comment: at a first glance your matrix seems right, but I can't validate on the fly. however, as a guess: for this to work as expected, it is crucial for the geometries to 100% align the way you expect them (e.g. that the boundaries do share a linear intersection ONLY, up to the last digit of their coordonates). you can try st_snap with a low tolerance prior to make sure they do.

Comment: Using st_relate() with two polygons : one in the case I describe above and the second clearly intersecting, gives the same matrix '212101212'. So I wonder if it is really possible...

Comment: that matrix says geom a interior shares a liear interssection with the boundary of geom b and a's boundary a point intersection with b's boundary...that hardenes my suspicion that your geoms do not align the way you see it

Comment: Reading your comments, I believe that I want the opposite : a 's boundary should share a line with b's boundary as intersection. And a's interior should share nothing with b's boundary. I guess my matrix is not correct (?) .

Comment: yes and no, let's get this right: my last comment was referring to the result matrix of st_relate() that you gave in your comment. if you used exactly that data for the matrix you gave in your question and if I assume correctly, then it's your data (the geometry) that needs to be aligned properly. again, if you used your matrix on the same geometries that produced the matrix via st_relate(), the polygons do not have equal boundaries due to minor differences in their coordinates or sth. similar. as I said, one possible workaround could be to use st_snap before applying the matrix

Comment: I have drawn the polygons with qgis and snapping options. So I don't think st_snap wold be useful but I will take a look.