# ST_RELATE - Intersect ignore shared boundary

Tags: postgis, postgresql, overlay, de-9im

Using postgis I am trying to find polygons that intersect, ignoring polygons that only have a shared boundary (edge).

1. ST_Relate(g1, g2, 'T********') is a standard intersection.
2. ST_Relate(g1, g2, 'TF*F*****') standard intersection with boundary touching false

An image of what I am trying to achieve (from: http://daniel-azuma.com/articles/georails/part-6):

[image]

I am confident in the underlying geometries as they are created inside of postgis by taking the overlay similar to [here](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiExamplesOverlayTables).

Similar to: [postgis st_relate polygon inside another and sharing a boundary](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259464/postgis-st-relate-polygon-inside-another-and-sharing-a-boundary) though I want to ignore cases where the only topological connection is the boundary.

Comment: I never used `ST_Relate()`, but I should try. But I'm lazy, so I'd just go with `ST_Intersects() AND NOT ST_Touches()` ... ;-)

Comment: I should test, but I believe that ST_Relate is problematic for the query planner, so Intersects and Touches might also be faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the first relation that you list does exclude the Touch relation, and maybe exactly what you want:
ST_Relate(g1, g2, 'T********').

The regular Intersects relation cannot be represented as a single D9IM. But the opposite of the Intersects - the Disjoint can be represented as 'FF*FF****'.

So if you want to exclude the Touch, use 'T********'. 
But maybe you want the Overlaps relation? That is, maybe you want to exclude the Contains and Within as well, then use 'T*T***T**'. It does not allow one polygon to be contained inside of another.

Both 'T********' and 'T*T***T**' allow only the right of the two configurations on your illustration.

Comment: It looks like my assumption that 'geometries are good' is actually wrong! Performing the initial overlay analysis I have overlaps with areas (in latl/lon space) that are 1e-17; looks like floating point issues! So 'T********' is spot on assuming the geoms are good.